# Multilistas enlazadas con ArrayList

Tags: java, hilos, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy creando un programa que simula el funcionamiento de una red de metro.

He llegado a un punto en el que tengo que crear las lineas a partir de un grafo donde tengo todas las paradas y sus conexiones respectivas. He considerado la opción de crear una multilista enlazada pero la tarea es muy pesada para la utilidad que le quiero dar.

Mi pregunta es : ¿Se puede crear un ArrayList, que este sea de tipo Arraylist y que contenga objetos de tipo parada (No es relevante la explicación del objeto parada para mi problema. Almaceno los datos y características de cada parada). Vamos que lo que quiero hacer sería algo así:

```
ArrayList <ArrayList><Parada> lineasMetro = new ArrayList<>();
```

Pero no es posible hacerlo de esta manera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que se puede:

```
public class Parada {

    private String nombre;

    public Parada(String nombre){
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }
    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

Y en donde la vayas a ocupar de la siguiente manera(ArrayList de ArrayList de objetos Parada):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Parada>> redMetro = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Parada>>();

//Linea 1
ArrayList<Parada> linea1 = new ArrayList<Parada>();

//Estaciones linea 1
Parada paradaa= new Parada("Centro");
linea1.add(paradaa);
Parada paradab= new Parada("Norte");
linea1.add(paradab);
Parada paradac= new Parada("Sur");
linea1.add(paradac);

redMetro.add(linea1);

//Linea 2
ArrayList<Parada> linea2 = new ArrayList<Parada>();

//Estaciones linea 2
Parada paradad= new Parada("Poniente");
linea2.add(paradad);
Parada paradae= new Parada("Centro");
linea2.add(paradae);
Parada paradaf= new Parada("Oriente");
linea2.add(paradaf);

redMetro.add(linea2);
```

Para iterar sobre ellos puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
    int numeroLinea = 0;
    for(ArrayList<Parada> linea: redMetro){
        numeroLinea++;
        System.out.println("Linea: "+numeroLinea);
        for(Parada parada: linea){
            System.out.println(parada.getNombre());
        }
    }
```

saludos desde CDMX

Comment: vale, gracias esto era lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente

```
ArrayList<Parada> lineasMetro = new ArrayList<>();
```

o mejor aún:

```
List<Parada> lineasMetro = new ArrayList<>();
```

Mas info: [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

EDIT:
Lo que necesitas es un [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Ej.:

```
Map<Integer, Parada> lineasMetro = new HashMap<>();
```

o

```
Map<Integer, List<Parada>> lineasMetro = new HashMap<>();
```

O lo que necesites.

Para ver otras implementaciones de Map: [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)

Comment: Igual no me he explicado bien. Lo que quiero hacer es un arraylist de varios arraylist y que estos sean de tipo parada. No un arrayList  simple de tipo parada. Quiero hacer una mullista

Comment: @ignacioaranguren Agregue un ejemplo de Map. Eso creo que es lo que necesitas.